# List box not showing vertical scrollbar WPF

Tags: wpf

I have a custom list box. But not showing scroll bar.

```
 <Style x:Key="noStyleToListboxItem" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="True"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit" Value="Pixel"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
                    <Border>
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Vertical Scroll bar is not showing.

Comment: change `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` to `True` or whatever it's called in your `ListBox`.... and the type is weird because it is code for `ListBoxItem`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility` only has an effect if the ControlTemplate actually contains a ScrollViewer:

```
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
            <Border>
                <ScrollViewer>
                    <ItemsPresenter/>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```